# Automating version numbers with Artifactory and/or Gradle

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, versioning, artifactory, semantic-versioning

We use:

- Gradle to build (our buildscript)
- Bamboo for CI
- Artifactory for bin repo

On Bamboo we use the [Artifactory Gradle plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) to publish built JARs to Artifactory.

**Does Artifactory, Gradle, or the Artifactory-Gradle plugin have the ability to automatically increment version numbers in accordance with `semver`?**

This mechanism would have to automatically increment the patch/build number, and take major/minor numbers in as CI script variables (that we would manually change when preparing a new major/minor release version). Furthermore, this mechanism would require the ability to reset the patch/build number to zero everytime a major/minor release occurs.

Is this an option? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/wiki/Release%20Plugins - semantic versioning is supported there.